# How to access Group subclass from User?

Tags: django

I have a model, Course, that subclasses the Group model. How can I access a users courses in a way similar to all his groups (e.g. `request.user.courses`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
qs = request.user.groups.filter(course__isnull=False)
for group in qs:
    course = group.course

# or shortcuts
User.get_courses = lambda self: map(lambda g: g.course, self.groups.filter(course__isnull=False))
# or 
User.get_courses = lambda self: Course.objects.filter(pk__in=self.groups.all())
# then
request.user.get_courses()
```

There is not direct relationship between User and Course. You need to fetch groups and then get courses by following OneToOneField, which is generated by model inheritance, between `Group` and `Course`.

Not sure why you subclass `Group`. You could also

```
class Course(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='courses')
```

If you really want to extend `User` to have `User.courses` like `User.groups`, you could

```
# Option 1
# in models.py
class UserCourse(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     course = models.ForeignKey(Course, db_column='group_id')
     class Meta:
         db_table = User.groups.through._meta.db_table

m2m = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='students', through=UserCourse)
m2m.contribute_to_class(User, 'courses')

# Option 2
# simpler but has duplicated m2m table and different API
# Also a Course instance will not have corresponding
# Group instance in user.groups, which may not be correct in logic.
class UserCourse(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='courses')
     course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

# Option 3
# just as Option 2, but w/ M2M API
class UserCourse(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
m2m = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='students', through=UserCourse)
m2m.contribute_to_class(User, 'courses')
```